# can you dont show constructor when made object

Tags: java

when you declare constructor in the class it gonna run if you made a object. is there a way to not show constructor when make a object without deleting the constructor.

```
class Test{
    Test(){
        System.out.println("This is Constructor");
        
    }
    
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test object = new Test();
    
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: By "not show" do you mean not executing it or merely hiding the output?

Comment: Do you mean like this?? :  java -cp . App > /dev/null

Comment: @Martheen More specific when i made object the console not gonna print "This is Contructor"

Comment: Then just redirect the output elsewhere like @NathanHughes say

Comment: jst dont do anything ini the constructor

Comment: @Martheen Can you help me little more what exactly i use ": java -cp . App > /dev/null"

Comment: @leoOrion That not the point of my question. i know, you can just not declare the constructor , or you can just make a method to do similar thing that constructor do. what i want is there a way to not call constructor when i dont need it.

Comment: dont create that object. A constructor is always called for creating an object.. What exactly are u trying to achieve here ? U cant hide output of only one constructor. All the moethods mentioned above will hide output of the entire java program. It redirects the entire sysout to `/dev/null`

Comment: @Copernove No. The constructor is *always* called during instantiation of an object. Unless you are asking how to prevent the *default constructor* from being called. Then you can write your own parameterized constructor if you are allowed to do so.

Comment: "not call constructor when i dont need it.", then just do that, only call the constructor when you actually need the object.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static class Test{
    Test(){
        System.out.println("This is Constructor");
    }
}

static class NullOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // do nothing.
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("creating Test...");
    PrintStream origin = System.out;
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new NullOutputStream()));
    try (Closeable c = () -> System.setOut(origin)) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

output:

```
creating Test...
done
```

I recommend to use the try-with-resources syntax to ensure that `System.out` is restored to its original state if an exception occurs during the constructor call.

If you are programming multithreaded, you also need to have exclusive control.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it `private` and expose it via a static factory method e.g.

```
class Test
{
    private Test()
    {
        //  do stuff
    }

    static Test newInstance()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: its gonna say "The constructor Test() is not visible"

Comment: @Copernove Try it.